# Dead keys not working in Emacs OSX

Tags: key-bindings, osx

I created a custom keyboard layout (using ukelele) where I use F1-F4 as dead keys to input pinyin (accents for tones). Is there a way to get it to work in emacs?

I tried the (require 'iso-transl) but that doesn't help (not sure if it is supposed to).

Comment: I use `(setq ns-right-alternate-modifier 'none)` to write in Spanish so that my right `alt/option` key can create accents and so forth.  I suggest that you type `M-x describe-key` and see whether your remapping efforts of `f1-f4` (presumably outside of Emacs?) are having any effect.  You may also want to elaborate as to what you did to "create a custom keyboard" so that people do not have to *guess*.

Comment: I added the custom keyboard part. I tried and if use other keys it sometimes works, for example using the ' key as a dead key is accepted but emacs (terminal too) doesn't accept Fn keys.